# XMLHttpRequest is working with IE11 only when fiddler is running

Tags: html, typescript, internet-explorer-11, angular2-http

I am new angular 2.
Currently I am working on application which has Padarn server at backend and HTML5 with Angular2 at front end.
I wanted ship one password protected zip file to backend, to achieve this I have written following code but that is not working with IE 11 (works properly when fiddler is running) . Same code is working with Chrome and Firefox browsers.

private makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array, files: File) {

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append("uploads", files, files.name);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                } else {
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        }

        xhr.open("PUT", url, true, ApplicationObjects.configuration.Username, ApplicationObjects.configuration.Password);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: I'd like to recommend that you use a tool for asyncronous requests. [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) will do just fine and it's way easier to use. It's also very well supported.

Comment: I am using @angular/http for all other services

Comment: What error message does the console of IE 11 report? Do you see that a request is issued in the network tab? Is `makeFileRequest` called if you set a break point in the debugger?

Comment: I am getting error code as 401 with status 0 in network tab. Yes, debugger is working with makeFileRequest  and it is giving authentication fail error even though i am sending correct user name and password for authentication.

Comment: can any one help me to overcome this issue.